# Compare performance of simple addition on one to many cores

Tags: f#

I read recently that ENIAC originally was capable of 5000 additions per second.  Naturally, I had to test my own laptop's capabilities and this became an instructive experiment in F#, which I suck at.

So, I am looking for feedback in two areas:

- What is the most concise way to write this in F#, or at least most closely aligned with the functional paradigm?
- Did I miss something for performance? Can this be done in a much more performant fashion?

```
module Program

open System
open System.Diagnostics

[<AutoOpen>]
module timingStuff = 
    let pickRunmode() = 
        Console.WriteLine("choose number of processes to spawn (default 1)")
        Console.ReadLine()

    let feedback (input : string) = 
        Console.WriteLine("you picked {0}", input)
        Console.WriteLine("now running")

    let quitOrContinue() = 
        Console.WriteLine("q to quit else continue with keypress")
        Console.ReadKey().KeyChar <> 'q'

    let rec addOne x stop = 
        let r = x + 1
        if stop() then r
        else addOne r stop

    let finished stopticks = (fun _ -> Stopwatch.GetTimestamp() >= stopticks)
    let secondsToTicks x = x * 1000L * 10000L
    let prettyNumbers (x : int) = String.Format("{0:#,0}", x)

    let printResult result start = 
        let final = (Stopwatch.GetTimestamp() - start |> TimeSpan).TotalSeconds
        let pretty = prettyNumbers result
        sprintf "performed %s operations in %f seconds" pretty final |> Console.WriteLine

    let op duration start = 
        duration
        |> secondsToTicks
        |> (+) start
        |> finished
        |> addOne 0

    let opAsync duration start procs = 
        [ for i in [ 1..procs ] -> async { return op duration start } ]
        |> Async.Parallel
        |> Async.RunSynchronously

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 
    let loop() = 
        let input = 
            match Int32.TryParse(pickRunmode()) with
            | true, i -> i
            | _ -> 1
        input
        |> string
        |> feedback
        |> ignore
        let start = Stopwatch.GetTimestamp()
        let result = opAsync 1L start input |> Seq.sum
        printResult result start |> ignore
        quitOrContinue()
    while loop() do
        ()
    0
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to Code Review! This is a great first question and I hope you receive great answers!

Comment: Instead of `sprintf .... |> Console.WriteLine`, you can simply do `printfn ....`, which does the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

So for my skill level there are some minor recommendations.
So for me `Feedback` would be a little bit more readable in this form:

```
let feedback input = 
    [   sprintf "you picked %s" input
        "now running" ] |> List.iter Console.WriteLine
```

There are some brackets that can be reduced, so simple write.

```
Console.WriteLine "q to quit else continue with keypress"
```

And finally there is no need to `ignore` `unit`, since `ignore` is a code smell and you actually don not need them so just ignore them.

And that is what I changed it to:

```
module Program

open System
open System.Diagnostics

[<AutoOpen>]
module timingStuff = 
    // no side effects
    let secondsToTicks = (*) (1000L * 10000L)

    let prettyNumbers (x:int) = String.Format("{0:#,0}", x)

    // no side effects if stop has side effect (but here it has)
    let rec addOne x stop = 
        let r = x + 1
        if stop() then r
        else addOne r stop

    // with side effects    
    let pickRunmode() = 
        "choose number of processes to spawn (default 1)" |> Console.WriteLine
        Console.ReadLine()

    let feedback input = 
        [   sprintf "you picked %s" input
            "now running" ] |> List.iter Console.WriteLine 

    let quitOrContinue() = 
        Console.WriteLine "q to quit else continue with keypress"
        Console.ReadKey().KeyChar <> 'q'


    let finished stopticks = fun _ -> Stopwatch.GetTimestamp() >= stopticks

    let printResult result start = 
        let final = (Stopwatch.GetTimestamp() - start |> TimeSpan).TotalSeconds
        let pretty = prettyNumbers result
        sprintf "performed %s operations in %f seconds" pretty final |> Console.WriteLine

    let op duration start = 
        duration
        |> secondsToTicks
        |> (+) start
        |> finished
        |> addOne 0

    let opAsync duration start procs = 
        [ for i in [ 1..procs ] -> async { return op duration start } ]
        |> Async.Parallel
        |> Async.RunSynchronously

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 
    let loop _ = 
        let input = 
            match Int32.TryParse(pickRunmode()) with
            | true, i -> i
            | _ -> 1
        input |> string |> feedback
        let start = Stopwatch.GetTimestamp()
        let result = 
            opAsync 1L start input 
            |> Seq.sum
        printResult result start 

        quitOrContinue() 

    while loop() do ()
    0
```

Comment: Why is `ignore` a "code smell"? In the current case, the code can be written so that it's not needed, but when using Framework/third party code that requires using it, there's nothing wrong with it.

Comment: Usually you should be interested in the result of a function call. If you get back `none` or `null` something did not work as expected, and you can react to it, ignoring it can lead to code that is not reasonable [why predictability is important](https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/is-your-language-unreasonable/).